# How to write compile.sh file for facerec_fisherfaces?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

On Ubuntu 14.4 with OpenCV 3.1.0 :
I'm trying to compile and run this file http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/_downloads/facerec_fisherfaces.cpp

but I don't know what to write in the compile.sh file to make it executable

I found this compile.sh but it doesn't work :

```
LIBS="-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_objdetect"

g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -fpic -Wall -c "untitled.cpp" $LIBS

g++ -shared -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -o libuntitled.so untitled.o -L/usr/local/lib $LIBS

g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -o untitled untitled.o -L/usr/local/lib $LIBS

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good answer for my own question :)

1. you'll need to rebuild opencv with opencv_contrib (please see readme there for build instructions).
2. please see 3.1 docs http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/tutorial_face_main.html#gsc.tab=0, not the old 3.0 ones
3. LIBS="-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_face"
4. the old 2.4 samples won't run as-is, please have a look at the current https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face/samples